# How to output PEM for *Holder objects with Bouncy Castle 1.46? (i.e. BouncyCastle 1)

Tags: java, certificate, bouncycastle

I am currently using BouncyCastle 1.46 (`bc-prov` and `bc-mail` libraries).  Moving to a newer version is not a possibility right now.

However, I am trying to rewrite things to move away from the various deprecated classes to using the replacement stuff like `X509v3CertificateBuilder` and `PKCS10CertificateRequestBuilder` and so forth so that when I do have the opportunity to update the libraries there will be much less coding changes to make.

Those builders return "holder" objects such as `X509CertificateHolder` or `PKCS10CertificateRequestHolder`.

What I am wondering is how to write them out in a PEM format?  First, `PEMWriter` is deprecated so I would prefer to not use it.  Second, even if I did use it, it does not handle the "holder" classes.  Now, it is true that I can turn an instance of `X509CertificateHolder` into a `X509Certificate` by using `JcaCertificateConverter` and then sending that to `PEMWriter` but again, that's a deprecated class.  As for `PKCS10CertificateRequestBuilder`, there's no converter in the 1.46 libraries to turn that into an instance of the old-style `PKCS10CertificateRequest` even if I wanted to do that (though I probably could do it by getting the encoded bytes from the former and passing into the latter's contructor -- though again, I want to get away from the deprecated stuff).

So, when you have objects that the various builder classes give you, what is the non-deprecated way of turning them into PEM data (other than getting the encoded bytes and "PEMming it" myself)?  If this was 1.51 I could use `JcaPemWriter`, but that doesn't exist in 1.46.

Answer (score 0):

The openssl PEMWriter has been replaced with PemWriter, a native bouncy castle implementation.

```
`   
import org.bouncycastle.util.io.pem.PemWriter;
import java.io.StringWriter;

class SomeClass(){
    SomeClass(){
    }
    public void myWriter(){
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        PemWriter pw = new PemWriter(sw);
    }
}
`
```